# Firebase - Subir varias imágenes

Tags: android, firebase

Estoy intentando hacer una pequeña apk para hacer un respaldo de las imágenes y subirlas a firebase.
A ver si alguien me puede ayudar. Al poner el boleano para que compruebe si ya está subida la imagen para pasar a la siguiente no llega al if para que lo ponga a true entonces solo me sube una imagen. No se como hacerlo para que espere a que el progreso sea del 100% y la imagen este subida para que cambie el boleano y pase a la siguiente.
 Si lo intento hacer de golpe la apk crashea.

Caused by: java.util.concurrent.RejectedExecutionException: Task com.google.firebase.storage.zzr@68a150 rejected from java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor@1933f49[Running, pool size = 2, active threads = 2, queued tasks = 128, completed tasks = 0]

```
private StorageReference mStorageRef;
private static final String CAMERA = "/storage/emulated/0/DCIM/Camera";
private boolean isDownloaded = true;
private TextView status;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    Toolbar toolbar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.toolbar);
    setSupportActionBar(toolbar);

    mStorageRef = FirebaseStorage.getInstance().getReference();

    status = findViewById(R.id.count);

    FloatingActionButton fab = (FloatingActionButton) findViewById(R.id.fab);
    fab.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
            uploadFile(CAMERA);
        }
    });

}

private void uploadFile(String path) {

    File directorio = new File(path);
    final File[] arrayFiles = directorio.listFiles();

    if (arrayFiles != null) {

        for (int i = 0; i < arrayFiles.length; i++) { //arrayFiles.length

            if (isDownloaded) {

                isDownloaded = false;
                Log.d("BOLEANO VUELTAS:", isDownloaded + " " + i);
                Log.d("FILE " + i, arrayFiles[i].getAbsolutePath());
                final int copia = i;

                Uri uri = Uri.fromFile(arrayFiles[i]);
                StorageReference filepath = mStorageRef.child("Fotos").child(uri.getLastPathSegment());
                filepath.putFile(uri)
                        .addOnSuccessListener(new OnSuccessListener<UploadTask.TaskSnapshot>() {
                            @Override
                            public void onSuccess(UploadTask.TaskSnapshot taskSnapshot) {
                                // Get a URL to the uploaded content
                                Uri downloadUrl = taskSnapshot.getDownloadUrl();
                                Log.d("SUBIDO", arrayFiles[copia].getName());
                            }
                        })
                        .addOnFailureListener(new OnFailureListener() {
                            @Override
                            public void onFailure(@NonNull Exception exception) {
                                // Handle unsuccessful uploads
                                // ...
                                Log.d("ERROR", exception.toString());
                            }
                        })
                        .addOnProgressListener(new OnProgressListener<UploadTask.TaskSnapshot>() {
                            @Override
                            public void onProgress(UploadTask.TaskSnapshot taskSnapshot) {
                                long progress = taskSnapshot.getBytesTransferred();
                                long total = taskSnapshot.getTotalByteCount();
                                status.setText("EN PROGRESO: " + arrayFiles[copia].getName() + "  " + +taskSnapshot.getBytesTransferred());
                                Log.d("EN PROGRESO", arrayFiles[copia].getName() + "  " + +taskSnapshot.getBytesTransferred());
                                if (total == progress) {
                                    isDownloaded = true;
                                    status.setText("SUBIDO:" + arrayFiles[copia].getName());
                                }
                            }
                        });
            }
        }
    } else {
        Log.d("VACIA", "NO HAY ARCHIVOS");
    }
}

public String pathUltimaCarpeta(String path) {
    String[] bits = path.split("/");
    String lastWord = bits[bits.length - 1];
    return lastWord;
}


@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
    getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.menu_main, menu);
    return true;
}

@Override
public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
    // Handle action bar item clicks here. The action bar will
    // automatically handle clicks on the Home/Up button, so long
    // as you specify a parent activity in AndroidManifest.xml.
    int id = item.getItemId();

    //noinspection SimplifiableIfStatement
    if (id == R.id.action_settings) {
        return true;
    }

    return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
}
```

}

Answer (score 4, accepted):

En este caso la [recursion](https://es.wikibooks.org/wiki/Programaci%C3%B3n_en_Java/Funciones_recursivas) funciona mejor que un ciclo, ya que un ciclo se ejecuta hasta que se cumple su condición, lo que hace que sea mas difícil de manipular las iteraciones de este. Lo que tratas de hacer con la condición `isDownloaded` es evitar que se suba una imagen al mismo tiempo que otra, que es el origen del error. Pero el `for` no espera a que la imagen termine de subirse para seguir iterando, este realiza las iteraciones una tras otra hasta que se cumpla su condición, por lo que este no espera la respuesta de si la imagen se subió correctamente. Como dije antes, controlar las iteraciones del for seria un poco mas complicado, por eso es mejor utilizar un método recursivo que se llame cada vez que la imagen se haya subido, este método lo puedes llamar desde el método `onSuccess`, que es el que se ejecuta cuando la imagen se ha subido con éxito.

```
...

// contador
int i = 0;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {

    ...

    FloatingActionButton fab = (FloatingActionButton) findViewById(R.id.fab);
    fab.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
            uploadFile();
        }
    });

}

private void uploadFile() {

    File directorio = new File(CAMERA);
    final File[] arrayFiles = directorio.listFiles();

    if (arrayFiles != null) {

        // Condición
        if (i < arrayFiles.length) {

            // Incremento del contador
            i++;

            ...

            StorageReference filepath = mStorageRef.child("Fotos").child(uri.getLastPathSegment());
            filepath.putFile(uri)
                    .addOnSuccessListener(new OnSuccessListener<UploadTask.TaskSnapshot>() {
                        @Override
                        public void onSuccess(UploadTask.TaskSnapshot taskSnapshot) {
                            // Get a URL to the uploaded content
                            Uri downloadUrl = taskSnapshot.getDownloadUrl();
                            Log.d("SUBIDO", arrayFiles[copia].getName());

                            // Si la imagen se sube exitosamente, vuelves a llamar el método uploadFile()
                            uploadFile();
                        }
                    })

                    ...
       }

    } else {
        Log.d("VACIA", "NO HAY ARCHIVOS");
    }
}

...
```

> Un método recursivo es uno que se llama así mismo.

He convertido el método `uploadFile()` en un método recursivo. Este se llama así mismo dentro del método `onSuccess()`, que es el método que se ejecuta cuando la imagen es subida exitosamente. El método`uploadFile()` funciona como un `while`, los `whiles` al igual que los otros ciclos están compuestos por tres partes: el contador, la condición y el incremento del contador.

Ejemplo:

```
contador
while (condicion) {
    incremento del contado
    ...
}
```

Lo que seria lo mismo a:

```
int i = 0;
while (i < arrayFiles.length) {
    i++;
    ...
}
```

Si te fijas el método `uploadFile()` funciona de manera similar: el **contador** esta declarado al principio de la clase, la **condicion** se realiza en el if que esta dentro del método y el contador se **incrementa** dentro del if.

---

Unas cuantas notas mas:

- No es necesario que le pases como parámetro al método `uploadFile()` la variable `CAMERA`, ya que la tienes declarada como una variable de la clase y por lo tanto la puedes utilizar en cualquier lugar de esta, sin este parámetro es mas fácil implementar la recursion.
- Los tres puntos (`...`) significan mas existencia de código.

Comment: Explicado perfectamente y funcionando. El único cambio que he hecho es el de la condición.
'if (i < arrayFiles.length - 1) {}'
 Ya que al ser recursivo en la última llamada se sale de los límites del array. Gracias @David.

Comment: como hacer algo similar pero que guarde las imagenes que tengo almacenadas en el recyclerview

Comment: Primero publica una pregunta de lo que quieres lograr